# zeroclipboard not working in my any browser ..when u do path zeroclipboard.js button click will be disable

Tags: zeroclipboard

ZeroClipboard is not working in my any browder i tried too much .. but i m new in js so i m haveing problam with this code . when i ZeroClipboard.js give then my click button will be disable and text not copy ... what should i do ..i want to make this code with jsp

```
<html>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

        <div id="d_clip_button" style="border:1px solid black; padding:20px;">Copy To Clipboard</div>

        <script language="JavaScript">
               <script language="JavaScript">
            ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('ZeroClipboard.swf');
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".clickme").each(function (i) {
                    var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();

                    var myTextToCopy = $(this).val();
                    clip.setText( myTextToCopy );
                        clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
                 alert("Copied text to clipboard." );
                });
                    clip.glue( $(this).attr("id") );



              });


        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```